# Defining the dot product without reference to an arbitrary coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, coordinate-systems

The dot product is of course independent of the basis or coordinate system.  This would suggest that the dot product is a quantity that could be defined without recourse to such a system.  However, every definition I can find forces you to express the vectors in some essentially arbitrary coordinate system.

This seems to be missing something.  **Is there a way to define the dot product without reference to any coordinate system?**

Comment: The dot product in $L^2([0,1])$, $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$ doesn make reference to a coordinate system. You are confusing the definition of a dot product in a space of vectors in which the vectors are tuples refering to the entries of the tuples to be referring to their coordinates. They just happen to coincide with coordinates in some basis, but they are really evaluations (a tuple is a function from $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ to the field).

Comment: In the space above the dot product also makes use of evaluations of the functions at points in its domain. But this time the evaluations needed don't coincide with coordinates in some basis.

Comment: So, being extremely pedantic when they defines $a\cdot b$ for $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ as $a_1b_1+a_2b_2$, that $a_1$ etc is really $a_1=a(1)=(a_1,a_2)(1)$, $a_2=a(2)=(a_1,a_2)(2)$, also evaluations. In this sense, this definition very similar to the one I gave in $L^2[0,1]$: $a\cdot b=\sum_{k=1}^{2}a(k)b(k)$.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it, not "dot product", but "inner product".  In any vector space, V, an "inner product" is a function from VxV to R, notated as $\langle u, v\rangle$, such that $\langle au+ bv, w\rangle = a\langle u, w\rangle + b\langle v, w\rangle $, $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle v, u\rangle $, and $\langle v, v\rangle \ge 0$ with $\langle v, v \rangle= 0$ if and only if v= 0.

Given an n dimensional vector space there are many different inner products.  And one can show that for each such inner product there exist a coordinate system such that that inner product **is** the dot product in that particular coordinate system.

Comment: Formatting tip: use \langle and \rangle, not less than and greater than.

Answer (score 2):

A dot product is geometric. Consider three points $O,A,B$ where we **assume** the line segment $OA$ is unit length. Assuming the concept of **orthogonality**, the perpendicular projection of $B$ onto line $OA$ gives a fourth point $C$. The signed length of $OC$ is the dot product of $OA$ and $OB$. If $OA$ is not unit length, then scale the dot product by the length of $OA$.

Comment: ... scaled by $OA$.

Comment: @Hellen Thanks, I expanded the end for better wording of OA length.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract (axiomatic) definition of an inner product doesn't refer to a basis (or coordinates) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong to say without qualification that the dot product is independent of the basis (or coordinate system).

What you might want to say instead is that one can precisely describe which bases the dot product **is** independent of, namely: the dot product is independent of the choice of an *orthonormal* basis; but the dot product will change if you instead pick a non-orthonormal basis.

Then you could go on to tailor your actual question: **Is there a way to define the dot product without reference to an *orthonormal* basis?**

And the answer to that tailored question is given by @Somos.